# 2d std::vector Contiguous Memory?

Tags: c++, vector

Consider the following code, which allocates a 2d `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` of size 5 x 3 and prints the memory addresses of each element:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  int n = 5, m = 3;
  std::vector<std::vector<int> >vec (n, std::vector<int>(m));

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
      std::cout << &(vec[i][j]) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
0x71ecc0 0x71ecc4 0x71ecc8 
0x71ece0 0x71ece4 0x71ece8 
0x71ed00 0x71ed04 0x71ed08 
0x71ed20 0x71ed24 0x71ed28 
0x71ed40 0x71ed44 0x71ed48
```

Of course, for a fixed row, each column is contiguous in memory, but the rows are not.  In particular, each row is 32 bytes past the start of the previous row, but since each row is only 12 bytes, this leaves a gap of 20 bytes.  For example, since I thought `vectors` allocate contiguous memory, I would have expected the first address of the second row to be `0x71eccc`.  Why is this not the case, and how does `vector` decide how much of a gap to give?

Comment: Why did you expect that? A vectors overhead size is not 0 ...

Comment: If you want the data to be contiguous, allocate a single vector  of size `n * m`, and then do the offset calculations yourself.

Comment: Or use `std::array<std::array<int, m>, n>` for 0 overhead. If you need a dynamic container do what @NeilButterworth suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overhead size of a vector is not 0. You have 24 bytes between the last element of your vector and the first element of the next vector. Try this:

```
cout << sizeof(std::vector<int>) << endl;
```

You will find the output to be 24 (*Likely for your implementation of std::vector and compiler etc*). [Live example which happens to match](http://ideone.com/MbK99A).

You can imagine the vector layout like this:

[image]

If you want your elements to actually be contiguous then you need to do:

1. Use a `std::array<std::array<int>>` for no overhead (*c++11 only*). Note that this cannot be resized.
2. Use `std::vector<int>` and the formula `row * numRows + col` to access the element for `row, col`.

Comment: Keep in mind that `sizeof(std::vector<T>)` is heavily implementation defined.

Comment: ~4 bytes of an std::vector are usually used for the allocator

Comment: @Fantastic Mr Fox There are only 20 bytes between `c8` and `e0`.  Where does the 24 fit in here?

Comment: @bcf Count again. 224 - 200 = 24.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox The available 4-byte blocks between `c8` and `e0` are `cc`, `d0`, `d4`, `d8`, `dc`.  This is 20 bytes.  Please correct me if I've missed something.

Comment: @bcf the c8 block is included in the calc. It is the start block.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Mr. Fox's results and solutions<sup>1</sup>. Disagree with the logic used to get there.

In order to be resizable, a `std::vector` contains a dynamically allocated block of contiguous memory, so the outer `vector` has a pointer to a block of storage that contains N `vector`s that are contiguous. However, each of these inner `vector`s contains a pointer to its own block of storage. The likelihood (without some really groovy custom allocator voodoo) of all N blocks of storage being contiguous is astonishingly small. The overhead of the N `vector`s is contiguous. The data almost certainly not, but could be.

<sup>1</sup> Mostly. The `std::array`s in a `std::vector` will be contiguous, but nothing prevents the implementor of `std::array` from putting in additional state information that prevents the arrays in the `std::array`s from being contiguous. An implementor who wrote the `std::array` in such a way is an occupant of an odd headspace or solving a very interesting problem.

Comment: Your second point is quite philosophical. While it might be true that the standard merely implies that `sizeof(std::array<T,N>) == sizeof(T)*N` holds true but doesn't define it, in reality however this is the case for most major compilers.

Comment: @user2176127 Agreed. I don't expect anyone to ever run into this problem without going out of their way to make or find it.